# .bashrc not being loaded/booted/executed | recognised on remote SSH login

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, remote

so i created this new user and i copied a .bashrc file from my ras pi's default 'pi' user to the new user i just created. then i login with the new users creds and they do not seem to work, for instance the prompt is not in color and my program welcome.exe has not ran despite me doing a sudo nano .bashrc while as a sudoer user and on the last line i did ./welcome.exe

im not usually good with this sort of help searching so if anyone needs any more data please ask and i will be happy to provide

Comment: Ive experimented with the other user accounts and they seem to be working file with the .bashrc file and they are all running separate custom scripts, it should be noted that they all haev higher elevation than this user i just created but the .exe is in the same /home/ directory as the user

Comment: who owns the file and what are thepermissions on the file? what does elevation higher mean?

Comment: The new user i created is called 'bob' when bob logs in through an open SSH connection neither does the color of the screen prompt change or any custom scripts run. bob has no special permisions and can only access/edit files inside his /home/bob/ directory, all the other users on the ras pi are in the sudoers file and have access to super user commands all their .bashrc files work as expected. Here is what i got from an `ls -al` `-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root  3512 Mar 23 03:07 .bashrc` this is in the /home/th-users/

Comment: change the owner of the fil to bob

Comment: i did the file is now `-rw-r--r-- 1 bob root  3512 Mar 23 03:07 .bashrc` but it still will use the .bashrc file to load from

Comment: nevermind Ive done it! turns out i just needed to link in a .profile or .bash_profile so it would start the .bashrc script

Comment: In that case you should either delete your question, or answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Per OP's own discovery, ensure that your `.bashrc` file is being called by either `.profile` or a `.bash_profile`.

For example, default `~/.profile` in Raspbian Jessie contains the block

```
...
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION"]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
...
```